# How to store data with js and redirect to a different view with the same click (Laravel 4.1)

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I have a view in my project that has a few steps.  The steps are handled through button clicks that take the user to the next step, and along the way, data is stored using JS and AJAX.  On the last click, I want a user to make a selection from a list of checkbox selections, and I want to store and use this data to affect the next view (this last button click should redirect to another view).

I can store the data fine with ajax, but what I can't seem to figure out is how to send the data to the next view.

Basically, I want to collect the clicked data, send it back to my controller with ajax, store it, and then use it in a hyperlink (using a route) to effect the next view (using SESSION data):

```
<a href="/fans/welcome_reroute/{some id}"><input id="btn-next" type="button" name="next" class="next action-button faded" value="Next" /></a>
```

I hope that was clear.  Any ideas on how to do this?

EDIT:

Ok, basically, it works like this:

Step 1:

Series of checkboxes (choose up to 3):

[]  []  []  []  []

"Next Button" takes you to step 2 (with js, view is the same)

Step 2:

Series of checkboxes (passed from before) (choose 1):

[id1] [id2]

"Next Button" takes you to another view

In the new view:

It could say something like "You chose id2!  Awesome!"

When a user clicks one of these boxes, and then clicks the next button, I want the id info from the box checked, to go back to my controller, be stored in my db (I am already doing this), but also, I want to carry this information to the next view, so that it affects the view using session data (using Session::get in Laravel).

My main question, is how do I pass this data back to the view, while also storing it using ajax and my controller.  I assume this needs to be done using a route that takes the id info, but how do I pass that id info to the button hyperlink as shown above?

EDIT 2:

```
function loadStep3() {
        var data = $('#onBoarding-hidden #step2').val();
        if(data) {
            var result = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            if(result[0]) {
                result = jQuery.parseJSON(result[0]);
                if(result.name) {
                    $('#step3 .name').html(result.name);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: explain more clearly?

Comment: made an edit trying to clarify

Comment: Do toy want to know how to store the data to use for next request after redirect or don't know how to send the data to server using ajax ?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far, post some code.

Comment: The first one please.  Basically, how do I get the data to be included in the route to the next view

Comment: You want data retention along requests? or on the same page?

Comment: I have already done it on the same page.  I want it carried to the next page.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood it correctly, you want to store something upto next request. For this, you can use `Session::flash('key','val')` to put some data in session.

This data will be retained in session for just one request. Reference -

http://laravel.com/docs/session#flash-data

Comment: I understand that but I am also running an ajax request concurrently.  I need to collect this data and store it as well as pass it along.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you just need to put the data to the `session` and from the next request you may access it and in this case you may `flash` the data to the `session` only to get it back for the next request. So you may try this:

```
Session::flash('identifier', 'value');
```

Then on the next request after you redirect; you may access that data using this;

```
Session::get('identifier');
```

So it could something like this:

```
Session::flash('myId', Input::get('fieldname'));
```

Then in your `view` on the next request, get it from the session using:

```
@if(Sessuin::has('myId'))
    <a href="/fans/welcome_reroute/{{ Session::get('myId') }}"><input id="btn-next" type="button" name="next" class="next action-button faded" value="Next" /></a>
@endif
```

For more information about `Session` check it on [Laravel website](http://laravel.com/docs/session).

**Update:** From your comment I got the idea that you may do it:

```
if(result.name) {
    window.location.href = 'url?name='+result.name;
}
```

Then on the next request (where you are being redirected) access the name from query string:

```
$name = Input::get('name');
```

Now you may use the `$name` as you want.

Comment: so where do I put the session::flash, in the controller function that is run during the ajax request?

Comment: Once you get the data then before you leave the page `flash` it.

Comment: If You want to redirect from same request then once you flash the data in the session send the response back to your client side `js` code then from there in the `success` callback use `window.location.href=url` to redirect to the 'url'.

Comment: I've added another edit, basically the result.name I have there, is what I want to pass to the next view.  Instead of having $('#step3 .name').html(result.name); I want to redirect to the next view, passing the result.name data.  Can you tell me what do to in the context of that?

Comment: Hey WereWolf, could you follow up on this?

Comment: What is that @user1072337 ?

Comment: Did you see my edit?  I basically want to take that variable in js (result.name) and pass it to another view.  How do I do that?